# Calculating mean and interquartile range of 'cut' data to plot

Tags: r

Apologies I am new to R, I have a dataset with height and canopy density of trees for example:

```
i_h100   i_cd
2.89     0.0198
2.88     0.0198
17.53    0.658
27.23    0.347
```

I want to regroup 'h_100' into 2m intervals going from 2m min to 30m max, I then want to calculate the mean i_cd value and interquartile range for each of these intervals so that I can then plot these with a least squares regression. There is something wrong with the code I am using to get the mean. This is what I have so far:

```
mydata=read.csv("irelandish.csv")
height=mydata$i_h100
breaks=seq(2,30,by=2)  #2m intervals
height.cut=cut(height, breaks, right=TRUE)

#attempt at calculating means per group
install.packages("dplyr")
mean=summarise(group_by(cut(height, breaks, right=TRUE), 
mean(mydata$i_cd)))
install.packages("reshape2")
dcast(mean)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aggregate()` to calculate the groupwise means.

```
# Some example data
set.seed(1)

i_h100 <- round(runif(100, 2, 30), 2)
i_cd <- rexp(100, 1/i_h100)
mydata <- data.frame(i_cd, i_h100)

# Grouping i_h100
mydata$i_h100_2m <- cut(mydata$i_h100, seq(2, 30, by=2))
head(mydata)
#        i_cd i_h100 i_h100_2m
# 1  2.918093   9.43    (8,10]
# 2 13.735728  12.42   (12,14]
# 3 13.966347  18.04   (18,20]
# 4  2.459760  27.43   (26,28]
# 5  8.477551   7.65     (6,8]
# 6  6.713224  27.15   (26,28]

# Calculate groupwise means of i_cd
i_cd_2m_mean <- aggregate(i_cd ~ i_h100_2m, mydata, mean)

# And IQR
i_cd_2m_iqr <- aggregate(i_cd ~ i_h100_2m, mydata, IQR)

upper <- i_cd_2m_mean[,2]+(i_cd_2m_iqr[,2]/2)
lower <- i_cd_2m_mean[,2]-(i_cd_2m_iqr[,2]/2)

# Plotting the result
plot.default(i_cd_2m_mean, xaxt="n", ylim=range(c(upper, lower)),
  main="Groupwise means \U00B1 0.5 IQR", type="n")
points(upper, pch=2, col="lightblue", lwd=1.5)
points(lower, pch=6, col="pink", lwd=1.5)
points(i_cd_2m_mean, pch=16)

axis(1, i_cd_2m[,1], as.character(i_cd_2m[,1]), cex.axis=0.6, las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have managed to put this into my code although I also need the interquartile range and don't see how to add this in to the aggregate() command

Comment: @HeatherKay: The simplest would be to replace `mean` with `IQR` in the `aggregate()` call.

Comment: Yes I did this put then it doesn't plot the mean with IQR 'error bars'

Comment: I'll mock something up.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm looking everywhere but just can't seem to work it out

Comment: I opted for 0.5 IQR marks, but you can adjust that to taste easily.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I'd managed half of that code it was the plotting and limits I couldn't work out

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution,

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
mydata <- data_frame(i_h100=c(2.89,2.88,17.53,27.23),i_cd=c(0.0198,0.0198,0.658,0.347))
     height <- mydata$i_h100
breaks  <- seq(2,30,by=2)  #2m intervals
height.cut <- cut(height, breaks, right=TRUE)

mydata$height.cut <- height.cut

mean_i_h100 <- mydata %>% group_by(height.cut) %>% summarise(mean_i_h100 = mean(i_h100))
```

A few remarks:

- it is better to avoid naming variables with function names, so I changed the `mean` variable to `mean_i_h100`
- I am using the pipe notation, which makes the code more readable, it avoids repeating the first argument of each function, you can find [a more detailed explanation here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pipe-r-tutorial).
  Without the pipe notation, the last line of code would be:
  `mean_i_h100 <- summarise(group_by(mydata,height.cut),mean_i_h100 = mean(i_h100))`
- you have to load the two packages you installed with `library`